# C# .NET Memory Management with Data Structures (Dictionary, List, etc.)

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, memory-management, garbage-collection

I am hoping that someone can shed some light on how .NET handles garbage collection in the following case.

I have a program where I need to do a very specific kind of "Find in Files" functionality like you would see in Visual Studio. I have to search potentially thousands of files, and I collect the results in a List(Pair()) object, where Pair is a simple class I created for storing a pair of items (obviously).

When I am through using what I need, I call Clear() on the list in order to get rid of the old information. This does not seem to help free memory because I can see on my Task Manager that the memory consumed does not decrease.

For a really large search, I am potentially dealing with 5,000,000 lines of information (approx. 500MB of memory usage on my machine) that need to be handled. When my search is through, the memory consumed level stays the same. I made my Pair class implement IDisposable, and that didn't help.

Any idea what I might be missing? Thanks!

Comment: What are you storing in the Pair object? Are you just storing file paths or are you actually holding on to some sort of Native resource (like a file handle?)

Comment: A call to "GC.Collect()" will force garbage collection to run.  This should help you see right away how much memory is cleaned up.  However, only use GC.Collect() for debugging this issue - don't leave it in your code unless you're absolutely sure it should be there!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The garbage collection will clear memory when *needed*, that is, not when you "clear" the list, but when it finds out that none of the items that were referenced in it are referenced any more and when the process/computer is running out of memory.

There is no need to micromanage memory in C#.

Answer (score 3):

The .NET Garbage Collector is surprisingly good. In general you shouldn't worry about the memory consumption you see in task manager because as you are observing, the garbage collector doesn't reclaim memory as soon as you would think. The reason for this is reclaiming memory is an expensive operation. If the memory isn't needed at that moment, why go messing around in there? The inner workings are of when it does go reclaiming space are pretty involved. There are different levels of collection the GC goes through (called Generations) to reclaim memory optimized for speed.

There are lots of articles which can explain this in more detail better than I can. Here is a starting point.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx

For now you should see at what point you end up getting out of memory exceptions, if at all, and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Clear()` all references to the `Pair` objects will be removed, this will cause those objects to be GC'ed *eventually* unless another object holds references to them, but you cannot count on when that will happen - it also depends on memory pressure.

As a side note you can use [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) in C# 4 instead of `Pair`.